# What are the most general methods for solving equations in closed form with Lambert W?

Tags: special-functions, computer-algebra, closed-form-expressions

What are the most general methods for solving equations with help of Lambert W function or with a generalization of Lambert W function in closed form?

I gave a method in MSE [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2578139/algebraic-solution-to-natural-logarithm-equations-like-1-xx-ln-x-0/2578259#2578259).

Which algorithms are used e.g. by the computer algebra systems?

Comment: If it's numerical methods you're after, there's some handy results in  TOMS743 : https://dl.acm.org/citation.cfm?id=203084

Comment: Now I found a new reference: Edwards, S: Extension of Algebraic Solutions Using The Lambert W Function. 2019 https://arxiv.org/abs/1902.08910

Answer (score 5):

This paper on Lambert W functions by Corless, Knuth and others should help.

https://cs.uwaterloo.ca/research/tr/1993/03/W.pdf

Comment: A collection of example equations is not a complete general solution theory. In particular, the relation to equations of elementary functions in general is missing. I assume the most general approach could be Rosenlicht's "On the explicit solvability of certain transcendental equations" for solving in differential fields. But are there further very general methods known?

Answer (score 1):

I have found the following (very easy) result to be absolutely essential in estimating
the number of terms to take in multiprecision computations:

Let as usual $W_0$ and $W_{-1}$ be the two branches of the Lambert function.

1) Let $a\in\mathbb R$, $b>0$, $c>0$, and $B>0$. The solution to the inequality
$x^ae^{-bx^c}<e^{-B}$ with $x\ge(a/bc)^{1/c}$ is given by:
$$\begin{cases}
x>((-a/(bc))W_{-1}(-(bc/a)e^{-(c/a)B}))^{1/c}&\text{ if $a>0$}\\
x>(B/b)^{1/c}&\text{ if $a=0$}\\
x>((-a/(bc))W_0(-(bc/a)e^{-(c/a)B}))^{1/c}&\text{ if $a<0$.}\end{cases}$$
In particular, in all cases, as $B\to\infty$ we have
$$x>((1/b)(B+(a/c)\log(B/b)))^{1/c}+o(1).$$

2) If $a\in\mathbb R$ and $B>0$, the solution to the inequality
$x\log(x)-ax>B$ with $x>0$ is $x>B/W_0(Be^{-a})$.